# Difference of apps created in `apps.twitter.com` and those created through Fabric

Tags: api, twitter-fabric

What is the difference between apps created in `apps.twitter.com` and those created with Fabric IDE plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Apps added via the Fabric plugin are given permissions to use certain parts of the API, such as those that Digits rely on or Twitter Kit, when developers start using those parts of Fabric instead of needing to manually request permissions.

Other things, such as automatically pulling in your app's icon to display when using Twitter or Digits works instead of needing to manually upload them.